# XML javascript draw network graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, d3.js

I am now trying use XML and JavaScript to create a donut chart.

I tried with this d3.v3.min.js library. I tried with my js coding which check and loop the data in XML and store in array. Then I tried run the coding to draw the network graph.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){

            var links = [];
            $(xml).find('name').each(function(){
                var name = $(this);
                var source = $name.attr("source");
                var target = $name.attr("target");

                links.push([source, target]);

            });


               var nodes ={};
            // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
            links.forEach(function(link) {
            link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
            link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
                    });

            visualizeIt();

        },

        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");      
        }

    });        

});
```

For the part of drawing network graph,

```
function visualizeIt() {



var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8);

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
function mouseover() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
}
function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);}

}
```

This is my data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<note>
<name source = "Math" target = "Science" />
<name source = "Bio" target = "Geo" />
<name source = "Science" target = "Astro" />
<name source = "Science" target = "Histo" />
</note>
```

I believed that there is missing part or misunderstanding of concept in first part of coding. Anyone please correct me.

Comment: you should do step by step

Comment: I did it step by step...just cannot figure out what is the error..I dunno which part wrong..either in part 1 or data.xml

Comment: if you did step by step you could have seen which part wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<course>
<source>Math</source>
</course>
<subcourse>
<target>Science</target>
</subcourse>
</course>

<course>
<source>Bio</source>
</course>
<subcourse>
<target>Geo</target>
</subcourse>
</course>
```

javascript coding

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
        var links = [];
        var nodes = {};
        $(xml).find('course').each(function(){
                var getSource = $(this).find('source').text();

                $(this).find('target').each(function(){
                    var getTarget = $(this).text();

                    links.push({source:getSource, target:getTarget});                   
                });
            }); 

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8);

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function mouseover() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
}

function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
};


},
});
});
```

This make me stuck few days. And finally free to post my answer here.